# error: src refspec master does not match any. failed to push some refs to heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I am working on a branch and pushing that branch only to heroku.

I have been doing

```
git push heroku master branchname:master
```

this has been malfunctioning since yesterday

keeps on getting these two errors

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:repo.git'
```

have tried

```
git pull heroku master
```

got this

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

then do another

```
git push heroku master branchname:master
```

and still getting the same errors

have tried

```
git push -f heroku master branchname:master
```

This may be a git issue. I don't have trouble pushing to bitbucket.

I read a couple of the questions/answers on stackoverflow but they are all dealing with github but not with heroku?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that what you are trying to do is

```
git push heroku master
```

or, meaning the same if you are currently on branchname

```
git push heroku branchname:master
```

From manpage:

> git push [repository [refspec...]]
>
> refspec...
>
> ```
>    Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. The format of a <refspec> parameter is an optional
>    plus +, followed by the source object <src>, followed by a colon :, followed by the destination ref <dst>.
> ```

Comment: I should have done `git push heroku branchname:master` and not `git push heroku master branchname:master`